# Locale dependent string sorting/comparison in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, string, locale

Is there any way through which we can sort/compare string in JavaSciprt that are locale-dependent? Like java provides us, "java.text.Collator" class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

Try this for example:

```
'ä'.localeCompare('a'); // Returns 131 in Chrome
```

Comment: What I want is that if there are some strings in some locale, say french and I want to sort them in the alphabetic order that french locale supports (which is different from english locale). Is their any method I can sort them?

Comment: No, you can't use arbitrary locales. Worse still, the implementation of `localeCompare` seems to differ between browsers. IE appears to use  the system locale whereas v8 [ignores](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=459) this altogether and uses the raw UTF16 values, whatever the system locale....

Comment: Yes you are right. LocaleCompare() is the only option we can use. It picks up the user locale that is set in control panel>regional and language settings>regional options.